# How do we prove this asymptotic relation $\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow \infty}G(k)=\sqrt{2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, asymptotics, hyperbolic-functions

I made the following observation with Mathematica:

Consider the infinite series,for natural number $k$

$$G(k)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sinh^{n}(\sqrt{k}\pi)}{\sqrt{(k+1)+\cosh{(2\sqrt{k}\pi n)}}}$$

then

$$\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow \infty}G(k)=\sqrt{2}$$

> How do we prove this asymptotic relation $G(k)\sim \sqrt{2}$?

Comment: Hint: multiply the fraction's numerator and denominator by $\exp n\pi\sqrt{k}$ and rewrite the hyperbolic trigonometric functions in terms of exponentials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $m=\sqrt{k}$. Using the exponential representations of $\sinh$ and $\cosh$, followed by the binomial theorem on the numerator of $a_n$.

$$\begin{aligned}
a_n&=\frac{\sinh^{n}(\sqrt{k}\pi)}{\sqrt{(k+1)+\cosh{(2\sqrt{k}\pi n)}}}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2^n}\frac{\left(e^{\pi m}-e^{-\pi m}\right)^n}{\sqrt{2(m^2+1)+e^{2\pi nm}+e^{-2\pi nm}}}\\
\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2^n}\frac{\sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i{n \choose i}e^{\pi m (n-2i)}}{\sqrt{2(m^2+1)+e^{2\pi nm}+e^{-2\pi nm}}}\\
\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2^n}\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i{n \choose i}\underbrace{\left(\frac{ e^{\pi m (n-2i)}}{\sqrt{2(m^2+1)+e^{2\pi nm}+e^{-2\pi nm}}}\right)}_{b_i}
\\
\lim_{m\to\infty}a_n&=\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2^n}\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i{n \choose i}b_i\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2^n}\quad{\text{by $(*)$}}\\
\end{aligned}$$

Therefore, as we can exchange the limits $k\to\infty$ and $m\to\infty$,

$$\begin{aligned}
\lim_{k\to\infty}G(k)&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lim_{k\to\infty}{a_n}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2^n}\\
&=\sqrt{2}
\end{aligned}$$

---

> **Theorem**: 
>   $$\lim_{m\to \infty} b_i=\begin{cases}1&i=0\\0&\text{else}\end{cases}\tag{*}$$

**Proof**

At $i=0$,

$${b_i}^2=\frac{1}{1+\frac{\left(2\left(m^2+1\right)+e^{-2\pi mn}\right)}{e^{2\pi mn}}}$$

So, as $m\to\infty$, $e^{2\pi mn}$ dominates the other terms and ${b_i}^2\to\frac{1}{1+0}=1$.

Conversely, since $2(m^2+1)+e^{-2\pi nm}>0$, $${b_i}^2=\frac{e^{2\pi m\left(n-2i\right)}}{e^{2\pi nm}+[2(m^2+1)+e^{-2\pi nm}]}\leq\frac{e^{2\pi m\left(n-2i\right)}}{e^{2\pi nm}}=\frac{1}{e^{4\pi im}}$$

So for all $i>0$, $$0\leq \lim_{m\to \infty} {b_i}^2\leq \lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{1}{e^{4\pi im}}=0$$

Then, $\lim_{m\to \infty} b_i=0$ by the squeeze theorem.

Comment: Addendum: the backbone of this proof is demonstrating that $\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{\left(e^{\pi m}-e^{-\pi m}\right)^n}{\sqrt{2(m^2+1)+e^{2\pi nm}+e^{-2\pi nm}}}=1$. And there's probably a quicker way of doing that.

Comment: In fact, we could just show that since $(e^{\pi m}-e^{-\pi m})^n\sim e^{\pi mn}$ and $2(m^2+1)+e^{2\pi nm}+e^{-2\pi nm}\sim e^{2\pi mn}$, so $\frac{\left(e^{\pi x}-e^{-\pi x}\right)^n}{\sqrt{2(x^2+1)+e^{2\pi nx}+e^{-2\pi nx}}}\sim \frac{e^{\pi mn}}{e^{\pi mn}}\sim 1$.